# Makefile crashes on target clean

Tags: c++, makefile

I'm tring to compile a c++ project with make, i'm not expert on Makefiles but it seems ok, what's wrong with this Makefile:

```
.PHONY: all test log debug clean cleanall

####### BUILD RULES #####################################################
all:        cleanall
        make debug
        clean
        make test 
        clean
        make log

log: CFLAGS := $(CFLAGS_LOG)

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJS) 

cleanall: clean
    rm -f   $(OUTPATH)$(APPNAME) \
        $(OUTPATH_DBG)$(APPNAME_DBG) \
        $(OUTPATH_DBG)$(APPNAME_LOG)

test: $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) -static $(CFLAGS) -o $(OUTPATH)$(APPNAME) $(OBJS) $(LIB)
    strip $(OUTPATH)$(APPNAME)

log: $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) -static $(CFLAGS_LOG) -o $(OUTPATH)$(APPNAME_LOG) $(OBJS) $(LIB)
    strip $(OUTPATH)$(APPNAME_LOG)

debug: $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS_DBG) -o $(OUTPATH_DBG)$(APPNAME_DBG) $(OBJS) $(LIB)
```

keeps crashing whit error:

```
make[1]: Leaving directory '/blablabla/dcp_edi/test'
clean
make: clean: command not found
Makefile:66: recipe for target 'all' failed
```

sorry but it really seems you can not post a question with too much code in it and i dunno what to write to make this post longer than this.

Comment: `clean` isn't a shell command. it's target in your makefile. `all: make clean`, basically

Comment: if i add `all:        cleanall
        make debug
        make clean
        make test 
        make clean
        make log ` it tunrs out the same error for target test.

Answer (score 0):

Your problems appear here:

```
####### BUILD RULES #####################################################
all:        cleanall
        make debug
        clean <<<<<<<<<<<
        make test 
        clean <<<<<<<<<<<
        make log
```

Everything that is put after the rules section is interpreted by make as shell commands to execute. As mentioned in the comment `clean` isn't a shell command but another rule defined in the makefile.

You can fix this with another recursive call:

```
####### BUILD RULES #####################################################
all:        cleanall
        make debug
        make clean
        make test 
        make clean
        make log
```

Comment: if i add `all:        cleanall
        make debug
        make clean
        make test 
        make clean
        make log ` it tunrs out the same error for target test.

Comment: `Makefile:93: recipe for target 'test' failed
make[1]: *** [test] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory 'blablabla/dcp_edi/test'
Makefile:66: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2`

Comment: @mattobob An the errors you see before these lines?? It's either the linker bailed out on an error, or `strip` couldn't be resolved from the `PATH` variable. It's not a problem of the makefile anyway.

Comment: Ohh yeah your right it doesent find the output folder on the machine, but it is supposed to create it by itself: `/usr/bin/ld: cannot open output file Release/tmux_mod_edi: file not found`

Comment: @mattobob _"but it is supposed to create it by itself"_ `ld` won't create any directories, you may introduce another rule or action to create the directory before calling the linker.

Answer (score 0):

You should rather write:

```
all: cleanall debug clean test clean log
```

(without any further lines). The problem is, that clean wouldn't be executed twice here. If that is not really needed, just eliminate the first `clean`. Otherwise, you could maybe split `clean` target into `clean-objs` and `clean-test`. If you can't split it, you can't get around submake calls (as already suggested).

I just wanted to emphasize the clean and standard way of solving this problem.